# Solving Differential Equation : $(1+\tan y)(\,dx - \,dy) + 2x\,dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Question is:

> $$(1+\tan y)(\,dx - \,dy) + 2x\,dy = 0$$

I tried the problem by:

$$(\tan y+1)\left( 1 - \frac{\,dy}{\,dx} \right) +2x\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

Then I put $\tan y = u $

$\frac{du}{dx}.\frac{1}{1+u^2} = \frac{dy}{dx}$

However going ahead doesn't yield any useful expressions. Also I don't see any clear product rule expressions.

How would you solve this ?

Comment: +1 I think it has a nice answer with $x$ as a function of y Saker.

Comment: Yes that is the answer, and it is admittedly nice.

Comment: Yes Saker it looks nice in the end. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(1+\tan y)(\,dx - \,dy) + 2x\,dy = 0$$
Consider $x'=\dfrac {dx}{dy}$:
$$(1+\tan y)(x' - 1) =- 2x $$
$$(x' - 1) =- \dfrac {2x}{(1+\tan y)} $$
$$x'  + \dfrac {2x}{(1+\tan y)}=1 $$
It's a linear first order DE. Use integrating factor method:
$$\mu (y)= e^y(\cos y +\sin y)$$
$$(xe^y(\cos y +\sin y))'=e^y(\cos y +\sin y) $$
Integrate both side:
$$xe^y(\cos y +\sin y)=e^y\sin y +C $$
Finally:
$$ \boxed {x(y)=\dfrac {e^y\sin y +C}{e^y(\cos y +\sin y)}}$$

Comment: That's a good approach, you don't see a lot of linear DE in $x$ instead of $y$, (at least not at my education level)

Comment: @SaketGurjar $\frac{dx-dy}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}-1$

Comment: @Aryadeva I understand you would laplace be helpful here too or exact DE

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Yes sure there are many ways to solve this I suppose

Comment: @Aryadeva Probably gonna try to solve this later I have to study for chemistry exam.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Well Good Luck for your exam then.