# Solving the following differential equation $\left( {1 + \tan y} \right)\left( {dx - dy} \right) + 2xdy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation $\left( {1 + \tan y} \right)\left( {dx - dy} \right) + 2xdy = 0$ ?

My approach is as follow $\left( {\sin y + \cos y} \right)\left( {dx - dy} \right) + 2x\cos ydy = 0$

$\left( {\sin y + \cos y} \right)\left( {dx - dy} \right) + 2x\cos ydy = 0 \Rightarrow \left( {\sin y + \cos y} \right)dx - \left( {\sin y + \cos y} \right)dy + 2x\cos ydy = 0$

Comment: Solve for the function $x(y)$. Hint : A particular solution is : $x=\frac{\sin(y)}{\sin(y)+\cos(y)}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving Differential Equation : $(1+\tan y)(\,dx - \,dy) + 2x\,dy = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624308/solving-differential-equation-1-tan-y-dx-dy-2x-dy-0). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(1%20%2B%20%5Ctan%20y)(dx%20-%20dy)%20%2B%202xdy%20%3D%200%24&p=1).